# FastAPI Vercel deployment not starting app

Tags: python, deployment, fastapi, vercel, uvicorn

I can't get the API to run on Vercel, running locally works just fine.

Since it's also my first time using Vercel, I can't seem to find logs. The build logs work fine (it's telling me 6 static pages, 0 of the rest), but when I go to the deployment page it serves me a `404` (not coming from my API).

Port `8000` doesn't load anything at all.

**Vercel.json**

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "main.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "app/api.py"
        }
    ]
}
```

**main.py**

```
import uvicorn
from os import getenv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(getenv("PORT", 8000))
    uvicorn.run("app.api:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=port, reload=True)
```

**api.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/", tags=["Root"])
async def read_root():
    return {"message": "Welcome to this fantastic app!"}
```

**Project structure**

```
app
 |- models/
 |- routes/
 |- __init__.py
 |- api.py
 |- database.py
main.py
requirements.txt
Vercel.json
```

What am I missing here? I tried to deploy using the Vercel CLI with `Vercel .` and also by committing to my GitHub repo, which works. The API just doesn't seem to be running.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `vercel.json` file to

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "/app/api.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "app/api.py"
        }
    ]
}
```